# Extracting Survreg 'scale' parameter to Stargazer output table

Tags: r, survival-analysis, stargazer

Hopefully someone can point me to the right documentation or hint for this query.

Given the following (dist="weibull" is the default)....

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
ff <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + sex, lung)
summary(ff)
```

The coefficients from the summary call are listed as summarised below, with (survreg's) 'scale' parameters included as part of the output...

```
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + sex, data = lung)
           Value Std.     Error     z        p
(Intercept)  6.27344    0.45358 13.83 1.66e-43
ph.ecog     -0.33964    0.08348 -4.07 4.73e-05
age         -0.00748    0.00676 -1.11 2.69e-01
sex          0.40109    0.12373  3.24 1.19e-03
Log(scale)  -0.31319    0.06135 -5.11 3.30e-07

Scale= 0.731  

Weibull distribution
<...snip...>
```

Then if I run the following...

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(ff, type="text", keep.stat="all")
```

I get the (really neat!) stargazer output, but no scale parameter...

```
====================================
             Dependent variable:    
         ---------------------------
                    time
------------------------------------
ph.ecog           -0.340***         
                   (0.083)          

age                -0.007           
                   (0.007)          

sex               0.401***          
                   (0.124)          

Constant          6.273***          
                   (0.454)             

====================================
====================================
Note:    *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

The stargazer pdf (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf) page 22 suggests support for the scale parameter, so perhaps I am misunderstanding the intent, or have skipped a page somewhere.

Comment: Just to add that I think(!?) that something might be do-able with the $icoef parameters in the survreg object......but my attempts have been fruitless (and messy) so far.

Comment: Have you looked at the `texreg` package?

Comment: @42 thanks for the suggestion. Are you proposing `texreg` as a known solution, or as a better all-round proposition (for example due to its greater flexibility with its custom extensions, for example). The reason I ask for clarification is that a first attempt with `texreg` gives me a `Error in nobs.default(model) : no 'nobs' method is available` for the `ff` object I derived in the code above. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: The latter. Unfortunately, I get the same error. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Well having been in touch with the package author (thanks, Marek!) and got a tip to use `add.lines`, the following seems to me to be a good start. The final empty string is to force a new line, and while I was mining the `ff` object I extracted the distribution type for use in the column heading.

```
stargazer(ff, 
          type ="text", 
          keep.stat="all",
          column.labels = ff$dist,
          add.lines=list(c("Log(scale)", signif(log(ff$scale),3)),
                         c("Scale", signif(ff$scale,3)),
                         c("")
                         )
          )
```

This gives the following added to the default coefficients mentioned above ...

```
--------------------------------------
Log(scale)           -0.313           
Scale                 0.731
```